# Networkx: Use a different color for each connected component

Tags: colors, networkx

I am using networkx. I mean to draw a directed graph using a different color for each of the [weakly_connected_component_subgraphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs.html).

This means using that color for both nodes and edges of the subgraph.
I followed the example [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/examples/drawing/weighted_graph.html),
adding a list of colors, one per node, as the parameter of `node_color` in `nx.draw_networkx_nodes`.

**The list of colors for nodes** was built with

```
colorlist = [ 'r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k' ]
ncolors = len( colorlist )
    wcc = nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs( my_network )
    color_nodes = [ colorlist[ 0 ] ] * nnodes
    isg = 0
    for sg in wcc :
        isg += 1
        color_sg = colorlist[ isg % ncolors ]
        # List of nodes in sg
        sgnodes = nx.nodes(sg)
        for i in range( len( sgnodes ) ) :
            color_nodes[ sgnodes[ i ] ] = color_sg
```

I took advantage of my nodes being labeled with a sequential numbering, starting from zero.

**How can I set the list of colors for the edges?** (perhaps the same issue would arise for nodes if they were not sequentially numbered).

I conceieve a way that gets    `sgedges = nx.edges(sg)`
and then iterates over         `nwedges = nx.edges(my_network)` and uses a counter, checking if each edge is in `sgedges`. If so, set the corresponding element in a list     `color_edges = [ colorlist[ 0 ] ] * nedges`.

This seems to me quite convoluted, and I guess there might be a simpler way.

Answer (score 4):

The drawing command allows you to draw a set of nodes and edges.  It also allows you to set the edge and node colors.  You can set the node color to be a single value in which case all the nodes plotted in that command get that color.  Similarly for the edge colors.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(my_network)
colorlist = [ 'r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k' ]
wcc = nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs( my_network )
for index, sg in enumerate(wcc):  #there's probably a more elegant approach using zip
nx.draw_networkx(sg, pos = pos, edge_color = colorlist[index], node_color = colorlist[index])
```

Since each thing you're plotting is actually a graph, you don't need to specify which nodes and edges are being plotted.  However, you could do that with the edgelist and nodelist optional arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is similar to what is done [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/examples/graph/atlas.HTML). I was aware of this. One should issue `plt.savefig` after drawing all `wcc`s. It produces the intended result, but using a different method from what is sought for. I look for a list of colors as an argument for `edge_color`, to call `nx.draw_networkx` on the whole graph. This implies identifying an index for each edge in the whole graph (so I asked "How can I set the list of colors for the edges?" instead of "How can I produce the drawing?")

Comment: Perhaps using `edgelist` works, I did not know about that. I will check it.